# Not able create controls in tab inside a GUI (Autohotkey)

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to put controls in tabs inside a GUI (AutoHotKey) But nothing showed up

I created a GUI where a second GUI appears when i click on the Add button,
In the second GUI i created two tabs where i want to insert a button in tab 1 and another button in tab 2 
If my syntax is correct it must show two buttons in two tabs.

```
#SingleInstance, force

; Layout
;--------

Gui, Font, s12
Gui, Add, Text, x70 y20, Available Shortcuts
Gui, Font, s11
Gui, Add, Button, x280 y60 w100 gAdd_Shortcut, Add
Gui, Add, Button, x280 y130 w100 gDelete_Shortcut, Delete
Gui, Add, Button, x280 y200 w100 gClose_App, Close
Gui, 1:Color, C8C8C8
Gui, 1:Show, w450 h300, `t
return


;Lables
;-------
; Next few lines of code is where i'm stuck and not working as it should!
;------------------------------------------------------------------------
Add_Shortcut:

Gui, 2:Color, C8C8C8
;Gui, 2: +Owner1
Gui, 2:Add, Tab3, x0 y0 w350 h200 Border,Add Key|Add Text|
Gui, Tab, 1               
Gui, Add, Button, x20 y50 w100 h20
Gui, Tab, 2
Gui, Add, Button, x20 y20 w100 h20 vEdit1
Gui, 2:Show, w350 h200, Add Shortcuts
return

Delete_Shortcut:
return

Close_App:
 ExitApp
return
GuiClose:
 ExitApp
```

The above code is written in AutoHotKey scripting.

Comment: Replace all "Gui, Tab," with "**Gui, 2:Tab,**" and all "Gui, Add, Button" with "**Gui, 2:Add, Button**" in the label "Add_Shortcut".

Comment: Thanks man it's working :)

Comment: Okay i got an issue again i replaced the two button lines with this

**"Gui, 2:Add, Text, x10 y10, Enter a text in the below field"**
nothing appeared inside both of the tabs.

Comment: E.g. **Gui, 2: Add, Text, x10 y20, Enter a text in the below field:** before **Gui, 2:Add, Button, x20 y40 w100 h20**. y10 is on the tab row  and cannot be shown.